# What verb akin to "refine" more clearly describes improving a skill that somebody is already good at?

Tags: verbs

What other verbs can be used to say "refine analytical skills"? I found "polished" and "sharpen," but I am interested in something better if there are any. The verb shouldn't indicate weak skills, but good ones that can be better. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Enhace, improve

Comment: How about "hone"?

Comment: Another possibility is "fine-tune," which implies that the skills are already reasonably good but can be improved further.

Answer (score 2):

**[Hone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hone)** is a good verb for this

> Refine or perfect (something) over a period of time

*"she has taken numerous workshops to hone her skills over the years"*

Answer (score 0):

Given that *the verb shouldn't indicate weak skills*, then "**to master**" perhaps; when "master" is used as a verb it's defined as:

> acquire complete knowledge or skill in (a subject, technique, or art).
>   "I never mastered Latin"

Saying "I never mastered Latin" could mean that I'm fairly good or not so bad at Latin, just not perfect or not as good as the best. It's not complementary (it could be being modest) about my previous skills, but it certainly implies that at least I've had some previous experience with it.

Or possibly "**to perfect**" (used as a verb), though claiming or even aspiring to perfection [might be frowned on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubris) in some circles. I doubt you'd say "to perfect" unless the skill were already good.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I think any single word suggestion is likely to be picked apart as they could all be taken to mean that the original state wasn't great, but let's try a few anyway.

To **[reinforce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reinforce)** a skill should imply that you already have it and the work you're doing is to make sure it either doesn't lapse or rather improves in mastery.

To **[elevate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elevate)** a skill also should imply that a degree of mastery is already present, and that the additional work is to attain a superlative position.

**[Raising the bar](http://www.yourdictionary.com/raise-the-bar)** is the act of improving something beyond the common standard. *"He is working to raise the bar on analytical skills"* implies that he is not only increasing his own skills, but that he is doing so to a level that hasn't been seen before.

Comment: Thank you very much,  Kim Ryan, deadrat, and Chris Subagio!