# Is there a word that describes "honed but in a short period of time?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

The exact definition of honed according to [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259583/what-verb-akin-to-refine-more-clearly-describes-improving-a-skill-that-somebod) (english.stackexchange.com link)
and other sources declare the meaning to be "Refine or perfect (something) over a period of time". Is there a word that means to refine or perfect something over a short period of time? The verb should indicate a consistent and time-committed refinement and/or perfection in a short amount of time. The subject of the sentence would be an event or small moment of time (few days/weeks/maybe months) in someone's life.

eg. That childhood experience (insert_verb_here) the boy's ability to interpret the microscopic cries for help his parents had unintentionally exposed.

Comment: I guess I would say "tuned up", if you want the "short period of time" thing.

Comment: I think it would make it easier to answer if you could explain what is going on here. What are microscopic cries (you can't see sounds with a microscope) and why are his parents making these noises? Also, is he going to help his parents to overcome whatever is causing them to cry? It seems a very odd scenario -- a child hears his parents crying for help and is able to interpret what those cries mean. Also I don't know what it means to 'expose' a cry.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK  I understand "micoscopic cries"  and "cries for help" as metaphors.  Unheard but, somehow, felt.  A child isn't expected to understand its parents "cries for help" but that is not what the question is about.

Comment: To *hone* just means to **sharpen**, and by extension to make perfect or complete. There is **not** necessarily any **time** (long or short) associated with it. (So I disagree with the definition you referenced, FWIW.) Honing as sharpening is the final step: fine, as opposed to rough sharpening. Depending on the tools used to sharpen the object, honing can be quick or long. An analogy would be sanding (with sandpaper): does it take a long time? Depends on the sanding tool used. It is not necessarily slower than more coarse smoothing. So one answer could be "*quickly honed*".

Answer (score 1):

Not single words, but I suggest

> - That childhood experience **"quickly enhanced"** the boy's ability to interpret the microscopic cries for help his parents had unintentionally exposed.

or

> - That childhood experience **"soon fine-tuned"** the boy's ability to interpret the microscopic cries for help his parents had unintentionally exposed.

"perfect", "sharpen" and "improve" are single-words, but don't include the time aspect.

> - . That childhood experience **perfected/improved/sharpened** the boy's ability to interpret the microscopic cries for help his parents had unintentionally exposed.

Answer (score 0):

**inculcated** may fit.

> Inculcate definition: *to implant by repeated statement or admonition, teach persistently and earnestly ; to cause or influence (someone) to accept an idea or feeling*.

Another possibility is **instilled** 
, but it refers to a period of months rather than days.

> Instil(UK)/instill(US) definition: *to introduce, implant or infuse a ​feeling, ​idea, or ​principle ​gradually into someone's ​mind, so that it has a ​strong ​influence on the way that ​person ​thinks or ​behaves*.